# Google maps v3 is not showing

Tags: spring, jsp, maven, google-maps-api-3, markers

Please help me. I'm making application using google maps. But is is not displaying and I do not know why! I have already surfed throw internet, but did not find answer why. Some times ago it was working, but markers was not displaying too, can you also answer why. Here is my jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kid Spy</title>
    <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&v=3&key=AIzaSyBfcW0KZvzDQcydwhJ7iLtsTE0haAEBbT8&sensor=false">
    </script>


    <script>
        var l=0;
        var coordinates;

        function setLength(){
           coordinates = new Array(l);
        }

        function setCoordinates(index, value) {
            if(index == 0)
                setLength();
            coordinates[index] = value;
        }

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                maxZoom:50,
                minZoom: 3,
                zoom: 3,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
            if(coordinates != null)  {
            var path = new Array(coordinates.length/2);
            console.log(path.length);
                for(var x = 0; x<path.length;x++){
                    path[x]=new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[x*2], coordinates[(x*2)+1]);
                }
            }

            var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: path,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            path.setMap(map);

            if(typeof path != 'undefined'){
                console.log("Creating marker!")
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: path[path.length-1],
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <c:forEach var="item" items="${message}" varStatus="loop">
    <script>
        l++;
    </script>

    </c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="item" items="${message}" varStatus="loop">
    <script>
        setCoordinates(${loop.index}, ${item});
    </script>
</c:forEach>

    <form:form id="info" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getnames" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date {dd.mm.yyyy}">
        <input type="submit" id="confirm">
    </form:form>

    <form:form id="addForm">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">

    </form:form>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

I'm making Spring (maven) project. Thanks!=)

Comment: Does your map-canvas div have a non-zero size?

Comment: `<div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>`

Comment: Thanks, problem was resolved, with your advice!!!!

Comment: Can you help. There is marker on map, and it is not displaying. Can you hrlp me why?

Comment: this `position: path[path.length]` doesn't look like a valid position (arrays go from 0 to length-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "map-canvas" div doesn't have a size.

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you help. There is marker on map, and it is not displaying. Can you help me, why?

Comment: Can you provide the code that is supposed to display the marker?  It isn't in your original question.  The HTML/javascript rendered by the browser would help.

Comment: it is in the methid initialize();                                          if(typeof path != 'undefined'){
                console.log("Creating marker!")
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: path[path.length],
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }

Comment: What defines path?  This `position: path[path.length]` doesn't look like a valid position (arrays go from 0 to length-1)

Comment: I have already change it on length-1, but it still not working

Comment: I ask again: what defines path?

Comment: my method in controller. It works normally. Polyline is showing ok.

Comment: But you are overwriting the path array with a google.maps.Polyline; I would expect you should be getting an obvious javascript error because path.length doesn't exist where you are using it.